# Remigrate data to new M2 database

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration-tool

How can i remigrate data to new database after one migration?
Workflow:

1. Migrate data from M1 => M2. In M1 database new `m2_cl` tables created.
2. Delete M2 table and try to migrate data from M1 one more time.

Is it safe to migrate settings and data one more time, when `m2_cl` tables exists in M1 db? Or should i delete something (m2_cl tables) first, and then do the migration?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to delete `m2_cl` tables.

This table keeps incremental data after you done initial setting and data migration.

You can perform many data and settings migration on same database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: welcome@SebastianT ....